# Pagination in Tridinad table in JSF

Tags: jsf

I am having a list of 20 rows, and i have used tr:table to list it with 10 rows per page.

{}

In this, the first 10 rows are getting displayed, but the next rows cannot be viewed.
Is there any solution for this.

Comment: My Code is as follows



<tr:table id="searchTable1" value="#{bean.model.sampleDataList}" rows="10" rowBandingInterval="1" var="arg" varStatus="row" emptyText="No Details Found">

Comment: Please provide Full data table code.
As well as check you have added Page Navigation code

Comment: <tr:table id="searchTable1" value="#{bean.model.sampleModelList}" rows="10" rowBandingInterval="1" var="arg" varStatus="row" emptyText="No Details Found">

      <tr:column>
       <tr:outputText value="#{row.index + 1}." />
      </tr:column></tr:table>